# Suppose $P \in \mathscr{L}(V)$ and $P^2 = P$. Prove that $V = \text{null}P \oplus \text{range} P$

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $P \in \mathscr{L}(V)$ and $P^2 = P$. Prove that $V = \text{null} P \oplus \text{range} P$ where $V$ is a vector space and $\mathscr{L}$ are the set of operators.

If $$V = U_1 + \dots +U_n$$ and $$\text{dim} V = \text{dim} \ U_1 + \dots \ + \text{dim} \ U_n, $$

then $$V = U_1 \oplus \ ... \ \oplus U_n.$$

We already know that $$\text{dim} \ V = \text{dimnull} \ P + \text{dimrange} \ P,$$
so only the former remains to be shown. Let $(u_1, \dots, u_n)$ be a basis of $\text{null}\ P.$ Extend this to a basis of $V$. Writing any vector $v$ in $V$ as $v = u + w $, where $u \in \text{null} \ P$, we must show that $w \in \text{range} \ P$.

We have $Pv = Pw$, or $P(Pv - w) = 0$. Thus $(Pv - w) \in \text{null} \ P.$ For some $u' \in \text{null} \ P,$ we have $w = Pv - u',$ but by construction $u' = 0$. Thus $w \in \text{range} \ P$.

I'm not quite sure this is correct.

Answer (score 5):

There is no asumption on finite dimensionality!
Let $v \in V$. $v=(v-Pv)+Pv$. $P(v-Pv)=Pv-P^{2}v=\vec{0}$. So $v-Pv \in$ null $P$. Clearly $Pv \in $ Im $P$. Now, let $v \in$ IM $P \cap$ null $P$. Then $Pv=\vec{0}$ and $v=Pu$ for some $u$. So $\vec{0}=Pv=P^{2}u=Pu=v$. The sum is hence direct!

Comment: Sorry I should have added that in my description of $V$. That was the proof I've seen, but I'd like to know if mine works as well.

Answer (score 1):

First, prove $range(P)+ ker(P)=V.$
Take a vector $v\in V,$ $Pv\in range(P).$ Now, take $w=v-Pv.$ Since $Pw=P(v-Pv)=Pv-P^{2}v=\mathbf{0},$ $w\in ker(P).$ Thus for every vector $v\in V,$ we can write it as a sum of two vectors from range and kernel. Hence, $range(P)+ ker(P)=V.$
Then, prove sum is direct. 
First $\mathbf{0}$ is in both $range(P)$ and $ker(P).$ Take a non-zero vector $v$ in $range(P),$ since $v$ can be written as $Pz$ for some $z\in V.$ Thus, $Pv=P^{2}z=Pz=v$, since $Pv \neq \mathbf{0},$ $v\not\in ker(P).$ Thus, $range(P)\cap ker(P)=\mathbf{0}.$ Hence, $range(P)+ ker(P)$ is a direct sum.